# Autolayout: resize UIView depending on content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, autolayout

Been banging my head over this one for a while.

On a button tap, I want to add FooViewController right to the window. The width of FooViewController will be dependent on the window width, and the height of FooViewController will be dependent on the height of a child UILabel, FooLabel.

```
- (void) didTapBtn:(id)sender {

float width, height, x, y, margin = 20;

FooViewController *vc = [[FooViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooViewController" bundle:nil];
RootViewController *root = (RootViewController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

vc.fooLabel.text = @"Dynamic text goes here. Resize view controller view frame so it fits to this label";

width = CGRectGetWidth(root.view.bounds) - margin*2;
height = CGRectGetHeight(vc.view.frame);

x = margin;
y = (CGRectGetHeight(root.view.bounds) - height) / 2;

vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

[root addChildViewController:vc];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:root];    
[root.view addSubview:vc.view];    
 }
```

As you can see, I'm loading FooViewController from a xib. Let's say in the xib, FooView has only one subview, FooLabel. FooLabel has a top, leading, trailing, and bottom constraint of 0 (it fills the FooView), and its number of lines is set to 0. What measures do I have to take so that instead of the FooLabel shrinking to fit the frame of FooView, FooView grows in height to fit the full content of FooLabel.

As the code stands now, the width and x values are set correctly, but the height gets set to the value FooViewController.xib defines. I understand why this is happening, as I'm not doing anything to tell it to resize based on the label content -- and that's basically my question: how do I have the view resize in this way?

Comment: Could you add a picture to help illustrate your exact layout?  This is a relatively simple problem in general, but I'm not sure what your exact layout actually is...

Comment: Just a single UILabel in the UIView. The UILabel has a leading, top, bottom, and trailing constraint to container set to 0 (ie, it fills up the entire UIView).

(Of course this isn't my actual layout, otherwise I'd just add a label to the window instead of a view controller. But if I can understand this arbitrary case, I can apply it to my layout)